# Android Studio -

Tags: android, android-studio, build-tools

I try to run the app, but `buildToolsVersion "20"` isn't cooperating. It gives me this error:

```
Warning:Project is building density based multiple APKs but using tools version 20, you should upgrade to build-tools 21 or above to ensure proper packaging of resources.
```

Then I change to this:

```
buildToolsVersion "21"
```

Then I get 105 errors looking similar to these errors:

```
/Users/Money/AndroidStudioProjects/LiFi2/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
/Users/Money/AndroidStudioProjects/LiFi2/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
```

....the errors finish like this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/Money/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

What to do?

Thank you.

Comment: You are getting these error because these are deprecated from API level 21. You need to remove that properties.

Comment: Thank you, but if I remove it, then I just go back to the same error "Warning:Project is building density based multiple APKs but using tools version 20, you should upgrade to build-tools 21 or above to ensure proper packaging of resources."

Comment: Do you know about this?